# playlist prev/next

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I use FLOWPLAYER
I have a playlist but I don't use their playlist plugin.
I have PREV/NEXT buttons, so I can navigate to one another.

demo :: http://baazooka.com/_ext/flowplayer/index.html

```
    $("#clips a").each(function(index){

    $("#next").click(function(){
    var nex = $("#clips a").next().attr('href');
          $f().play(nex);
          return false;
   });
   $("#previous").click(function(){
    var pre = $("#clips a").prev().attr('href');
          $f().play(pre);
          //return false;
   });
   
});
```

but it only works one time.
the value of #next and #previous keep the same value.
it doesn't in crement or decrement.

i've found this below but still doesn't work. it skips videos...

```
var link = $("#clips a");
link.each(function(i){
$("#next").click(function(){
 var nex = link.eq(i+1).attr('href');
      $f().play(nex);
      return false;
});
$("#previous").click(function(){
 var pre = link.eq(i-1).attr('href');
      $f().play(pre);
      return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you wanna do that with pure javascript or Jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#clips a").each(function(index){
  $("#next").click(function(){
    var nex = $("#clips a.playing:first").next().attr('href');
    $f().play(nex);
    return false;
  });
  $("#previous").click(function(){
    var pre = $("#clips a.playing:first").prev().attr('href');
    $f().play(pre);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Just select `.playing`, not all links.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want completely. I assume you have the looping in there for a reason. But, I'm guessing you want to refer to the current link instance that you are looping over instead of the `$("#clips a")` - this isn't an iterator.

```
$("#clips a").each(function(index){
    var link = $(this);

    $("#next").click(function(){
    var nex = link.next().attr('href');
          $f().play(nex);
          return false;
   });

   $("#previous").click(function(){
    var pre = link.prev().attr('href');
          $f().play(pre);
          //return false;
   });
});
```

If you just want to do this on an element that is being played, give it a class 'playing' and only work with the link that has that class `$("#clips a.playing")`. No need to loop over all of them.